# Calculating calories carbs and fats and proteins in homemade whole milk and cream Greek yoghurt

Tags: yogurt, low-carb

I make homemade yoghurt using 4 litres of whole milk and 2 cups of 10% cream. I ferment this for 24 hours, then I put it in the fridge for four hours, and then strain it overnight to make a very thick Greek yogurt.
How do I go about calculating carbs, protein, fat and calories? Assuming that most of the sugar has been eaten up during the 24 hour fermentation process? Appreciate your help I am on a low-carb diet.

Comment: Welcome to SA!  Unfortunately, dietary health advice is off-topic for this board; we're simply not qualified to answer such questions.  See: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Hi! I am afraid that your question is unanswerable, since nobody can tell you what nutrients you are discarding with the whey without measuring them. But for the last step before straining, see the related question. Also note that your assumption of the sugars being fermented away is not true.

Comment: @rumtscho It doesn't look like they are asking anyone to tell them what nutrients are being discarded. They seem to be asking "How do I calculate....?" and not asking for actual Nutrition info. It seems your last two sentences would be closely related to an answer to their question.